# Formula of area enclosed by the graphs of two quadratic functions

Tags: area, curves

I have recently encountered a simple hands on formula to calculate the area between two quadratic curves:

> $$\begin{align}
> y &= a_1 x^2 + b_1 x + c_1 \\
> y &= a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2
> \end{align}$$
>
> $$\text{area enclosed} = \frac{(B^2-4A C)^{3/2}}{6A^2}$$
>   where
>   $$A := a_1 - a_2 \qquad B := b_1 - b_2 \qquad C := c_1 - c_2$$

([original image](https://i.postimg.cc/cLyQ4nWF/IMG-20200418-115049-1.jpg))

Can anyone verify the consistency of this formula? I don't find it accurate to geometric level.

Comment: The formula looks fine to me (assume $B^2 - 4AC \ge 0$, otherwise the curves won't intersect and the area is $\infty$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting the curves, we find that the $x$-coordinates of the points of intersection satisfy
$$(a_1 - a_2) x^2 + (b_1 - b_2 )x + (c_1 - c_2) = 0 \tag{1}$$
so that, using the definitions of $A$, $B$, $C$,
$$\{x_-,x_+\} = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2-4A C} }{2A} \tag{2}$$
A little symbol-crunching gives
$$\begin{align}
x_{+}-x_{-} &= \phantom{-}\frac{1}{A}\sqrt{B^2-4A C} \tag{3}\\[4pt]
x_{+}^2-x_{-}^2 &= -\frac{B}{A^2}\sqrt{B^2-4A C} \tag{4}\\[4pt]
x_{+}^3-x_{-}^3 &= \phantom{-}\frac{1}{A^3}(B^2-AC)\sqrt{B^2-4AC} \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
Then, the *signed* area between the curves is given by the integral
$$\begin{align}
&\int_{x_-}^{x_+}(a_1 - a_2) x^2 + (b_1 - b_2 )x + (c_1 - c_2) \;dx \tag{6}\\[4pt]
&= \int_{x_-}^{x_+}Ax^2 + Bx + C \;dx \tag{7}\\[4pt]
&=\frac13A x^3+\frac12B x^2+Cx\;\big|_{x_-}^{x_+} \tag{8}\\[4pt]
&=\frac13A(x_{+}^3-x_{-}^3)+\frac12B(x_{+}^2-x_{-}^2)+C(x_{+}-x_{-}) \tag{9}\\[4pt]
&= \sqrt{A^2-4AC}\left(\frac13A\cdot\frac{1}{A^3}(B^2-AC)
-\frac12B\cdot\frac{B}{A^2}
+C\cdot\frac1{A} \right) \tag{10}\\[4pt]
&= -\frac{(B^2-4AC)^{3/2}}{6A^2} \tag{11}
\end{align}$$
Taking the absolute value gives the desired formula. $\square$

As @achillehui notes in a comment to the question (and, as is clear from $(2)$), we require $B^2-4AC\geq 0$ for the intersections to be real and the curves to meet. We also require $A\neq 0$; otherwise, the represented graphs are congruent parabolas that either coincide or meet only once.